# lottery generation function using 'void'

Tags: c

i need to use 'void lotto_gen(void)' function but i don't know how to make this =>    lotto[i + (j * 5)] = lotto_gen(); right. output should look like this picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BAKc.png)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

void lotto_gen()
{
    int ball = 1 + rand() % 45; 
}
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int r;
    r = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = r;
}
void shuffle(int* arr, int size)
{
    int i, r;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        r = rand() % (size - i) + i;
        swap(arr + i, arr + r);
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    int lotto[50] = { 0 };
    int size = sizeof(lotto) / sizeof(lotto[0]);
    srand(time(0));

    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            lotto[i + (j * 5)] = lotto_gen();
    }
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        printf("[");
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            printf("%d ", lotto[i + (j * 5)]);
        printf("]\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You got an *error* from the compiler? You **must** include the error messages from the compiler into the question itself!

Comment: Void functions have no return, but you seem to want to return from it anyway. Does it have to be void?

Comment: It states that the problem does not require parameters in  lotto_gen()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, "It states that the problem does not require parameters in lotto_gen()" -- If this is only the problem constraint, then you have your freedom to choose the return type. Why not go with `int lotto_gen(void)` instead of `void lotto_gen(void)`. You can have your lotto_gen() function like this:

```
/* ..... */

int lotto_gen(void)
{
    return (1 + rand() % 45); 
}

/* .... */
```